# Authlogic - how to make a registration and don't log in the new account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, authlogic

I have an administration where I can create new accounts. For creating new accounts I am using the gem Authlogic.
As admin, I would like to create a new account for a new user without log in (the common process with Authlogic is filling form -> sending form -> account is created + the new user is logged in). I need it without log in.

Here's the standard code for creating new account:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How to skip the log-in thing?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a session[:user_id] somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `save_without_session_maintenance` instead of `save` which will just save the user without logging in.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save_without_session_maintenance
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```